# Singleton Pattern With REST

Tags: c#, singleton

I currently have a bit of a problem with an app i'm working on.

I currently use a singleton design pattern to get at an object which holds a reference to an external file, however the problem I have is that after this has been ran one time the collection won't update to reflect any change in the external file (since the Statistics object already exists and it only creates a new variable based on the external file if the Statistics object doesn't exist).

My singleton is as follows:

```
    private static Statistics statistics;

    public static Statistics Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (statistics == null)
            {
                statistics = new Statistics();
            }
            return statistics;
        }
        private set
        {
            statistics = value;
        }
    }
```

And the constructor for the Statistics class contains the following code:

```
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://website.co.uk/textfile.txt");
        httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

        using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

This read in an external text file.

The problem I have is that if this is ran more than once then the values are already set, which is no use to me as they'll be updated a few times every week on the external text file!

Apologies if I haven't explained this very well however I think it may be a common problem many have came across.

Comment: First, your singleton is not thread safe, [Jon Skeet has a wonderful section on Singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy) that you should check out.  Also, I think its a bad idea to put web request code in a constructor, _especially_ considering your predicament... Take a step back and think about this, you've implemented a singleton, the web request is being done in your constructor...  Why would you ever expect to have fresh data?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, your singleton is *not thread safe*.  [Jon Skeet has a wonderful section on Singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy) that you should check out.

Now, on to your next problem.

A properly implemented Singleton pattern means there will **only ever be one instance of an object**.  Your web request is being performed *inside your constructor*.  Your constructor will only ever execute once since you have implemented *the singleton pattern*.  Do you see where I am going with this?

Without knowing much more about your problem, I honestly dont see how a singleton is needed here.  Why not just have a method that is called whenever you need fresh data?

Comment: Good point.I have used singletons in the past but now this case is a fair bit different. Thanks for the comments, they have given me a lot to think about.